# Proper way to render content without flickering ? React + Redux + TS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Could you help me with the logic for rendering content?
I'm doing pet-project with React, Redux, TS and have troubles with content rendering on page load.

Actually there are two problems.

**The first problem:**

1. When I click on a card the GET request is sent for the card data.
2. Card's page is opens (dynamic routing with useParams)
3. When data is received from server it sends to Redux State
4. Page renders is ok (because initial state was empty).

Then I click on another card and here's the problem:
5) I click on another card and send GET request for the new date.
6) At this moment state stores previous card data and renders it
7) New data comes from servers and renders.
8) For time very small amount of time I see previous card data ...it's flickring. Gif below

[image]

**My question is:** should I reset card state to its initial state (empty state) when clicking on a card? Or there should be another way to do this?

Second problem:
To fix first propblem I addeed onClick function which resets card state to its initial state:

```
const initialState: IMovieState = {
  movie: {
    filmId: 0,
    nameRu: '',
    nameEn: '',
    webUrl: '',
    posterUrl: '',
    year: 0,
    filmLength: '',
    slogan: '',
    description: '',
    type: '',
    countries: [],
    genres: [],
    rating: {
      rating: 0,
      ratingVoteCount: 0,
      ratingImdb: 0,
      ratingImdbVoteCount: 0,
    },
    images: {
      posters: [],
    },
  },
  isLoading: false,
  movieError: null,
};
```

This seems to fix problem 1, but there's another...on page Load there's yellow button and image's alt data (which fail to load) is visible at the top left corner. Gif below.
[image]

**My question is:** should I add a condition: if object key (no matter what key) has data then render it or should I add a new key in state something like isData: false/true and condition will be if data=true then render it.

MoviePage.tsx

```
interface IMovieProps {
  filmId: string;
}

const MoviePage: React.FC = () => {
  const { filmId } = useParams<IMovieProps>();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { isLoading, movie, movieError } = useTypedSelector((state) => state.singleMovie);
  const { nameRu, nameEn, description, posterUrl, year, genres, filmLength } = movie;
  
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchMovie(filmId));
  }, [filmId, dispatch]);


  return (
    <section className={styles.section}>

      <div className={styles.backgroundImage} style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${posterUrl})` }} />

      {isLoading && <Preloader />}

      {!isLoading && !!movieError && <Message message={movieError} />}

      {!isLoading && !movieError && (
        <>
          <GoBackLink text={'Назад'} />

          <div className={styles.content}>
            <img src={posterUrl} alt='Постер' className={styles.poster} />
            <div>
              <h1 className={styles.title}>{nameRu}</h1>
              <h2 className={styles.subtitle}>
                {nameEn && `${nameEn}, `}
                <span>{year}</span>
              </h2>
              {filmLength && <p className={styles.subtitle}>Продолжительность: {filmLength} ч</p>}

              <ul className={styles.genresList}>
                {genres.map(({ genre }, idx) => (
                  <Genres genre={genre} key={idx} />
                ))}
              </ul>

              {description && (
                <>
                  <h3 className={styles.heading}>Описание</h3>
                  <p className={styles.text}>{description}</p>
                </>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        </>
      )}
    </section>
  );
};

export default MoviePage;
```

State of a card on click:
[image]

Comment: when clicking on a card , what do you do ? Are you moving to a different page and making API call to get the additional info for the selected card ? or are you setting the selected card info in state ?

Comment: When clickling on a card I send GET request for card's data. At the same time I move to card page with useParams

Comment: Can you add the code for your card page ?

Comment: The answer to your firs question is "yes, resetting the state in redux when you click on another card is a logical course of actions", just remember to *not* reset the state if you click on the same card (e.g. by checking the the card ID in the action payload is different from the one in the state). For what concerns the second question, that happens because you try loading some images before your GET request returns any value; you can fix that by using conditional render (render the images only if/when the card state is not null or undefined)

Comment: @secan as I use redux and TS ...the initial state is described. So when I click on a card for the first time - it's object with many empty props...so I can add condition null || undefined. I added screenshot of the first click on a card

Comment: Then just check that `posterUrl` and `posterUrlPreview` are not empty strings; the concept is the same: if they are empty strings render nothing (or a loader, if you prefer), if they have a value render the image. ;)

Comment: I also had this problem and it was in the reducer, please share it

Comment: ... anyway, I do not see any real benefit in having `movie` initialized as an object with empty properties rather than to `null`. You might want to consider whether to modify your initial state.

Comment: one approach is to not have the selected movie state inside the store . You can just have a component state inside the MoviePage.tsx , which will remove your problem of clearing the selected card state each time . If you still want to have it in the store then you can add the clear logic in the useEffect's return which will act as a componentWillUnMount . And as @secan mentioned have your initial state as null which is more clean .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I like to do is that I like to use condition with useState() as well as check that the particular key has data. I don't reset the state before each click. Rather I check if the particular post key has already data present in redux state. If that particular key has data then I just use that data and do not make a fetch request every time the same component is rendered. If it does not have data then i make request.

1- Check if the item key has already data present. if it has then no need to make a fetch request, use the data to render component.
2- concat data to redux store. Don't override the state.
3- store data in the form of Objects. Where keys would be item's unique key. This way you can check if key is present (eg: data[key]?.length > 0)


Hope it helps.

```js
// example
  
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const data = useSelector(getItemData) // here getItemData is a seletor from reselect library 
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  
  
  const hasData = Boolean(data.length)
  useEffect(() => {
    if (hasData) return;
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      await dispatch(fetchItems()); // make fetchItems redux thunk async as well
      setLoading(false)
    }

    fetchData()
  }, [condition]);


  if (loading) return <div>Loading ...</div>
  
  return <MyComponent />
```